run an input/output waiting application in function in background getting output of that function
I have a shell function
func() {
    read < /dev/ttyUSB3 &
    PID=$!
    echo "$PID"
}

do not focus on its exact purpose, the thing is that I need to run some app (in this case read) in background, and get its pid to kill in the future.
The problem I get is, in calling script
MYVAR=$(func)

is hung. I suspect it waits for termination of the background process (e.g. its stdout close), but why?
Simpler deal:
echo $(read < /dev/ttyUSB3 &)

also hangs, ^C does not work anymore, ^Z too.
I would expect echo to return empty string, as read starts, goes into background and says nothing into the stdout. When echo ends, that read process will become zombie.
Something is obviously broken in my logic. What is it?
How do I run input/output waiting application into background letting it do what it needs to, getting its PID without further problems like this? I have tried doing return from the function, but for some reason it truncates PID value being returned into 8-bit value.
Edit:
Thanks Barmar for the suggestion. I have chosen bad example. In my case I already perform output to the waiting device file using echo:\
func() {
    echo "something" > /dev/ttyUSB3 &
    PID=$!
    echo "$PID"
}

and is call
MYVAR=$(func)

hangs at the exit of the function.

Even simpler demo: echo $(sleep 10 &). This waits for the 10-second sleep to finish.

See the linked duplicate. Use read < /dev/ttyUSB3 >/dev/null &

@Barmar Thanks. What's about command which already has output redirected to the device file waiting? For example echo $(echo something > /dev/somedevice &)?

That should work. The important thing is that stdout is not connected to the pipe for the command substitution.

@Barmar that's why I ask. It does not work. Let me edit the question

There shouldn't be any hanging with a simple echo statement. Could it be blocking trying to open the device? Can you reproduce it when writing to a regular file instead of a device, e.g. echo something > /tmp/something &?

Try using (echo "someting" > /dev/ttyUSB3) & to ensure that it opens the device in the subprocess rather than the original shell process.

Same with brackets. The special device is processing echoed request within its write function and can (in this exact case) only be terminated by signaling to it. That's why I need its (echo's) PID.

If you can come up with some way to replicate this without requiring this special device, we may be able to help. But I'm really not sure why it should matter what you're redirecting output to.

All that should matter is that there's nothing in the function whose stdout is connected to the pipe and it's taking time to run.

If you simply run the function without $() does it complete immediately?

Yes, I caught the issue when tried to get echoed value of PID out of the function using $() in the main script. Otherwise there's no problem. It exits into the shell and can be foregrounded and ^C'ed

I've reopened since the canonical solution isn't working for you, but I'm not sure if we'll be able to help without a reproducible example.

I have solved the issue after getting another problem.
The problem was in inability to kill the process employing the echo to the device file. The script being killed has trap set, and its trap code was never invoked (possible Linux bug?). But it was clear that when script process was tried to be killed, the write to device file restarts.
The cause was the driver returning -ERESTARTSYS instead of -EINTR, causing the current driver write process terminate, but being restarted without going into user space. This means if system call is restartable through -ERESTARTSYS, you'll not be able to terminate related I/O until it finishes naturally.
